# Составить программу для определения значения функции Y

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Составить программу для определения значения функции у(x). Предусмотреть вывод сообщения о том, по какой ветви происходило вычисление значения аргумента функции х.
Указание: k, z– неявные параметры функции y(x) считаются входными данными.

```
 int k = 0;
 int z = 0;
 int x = 0;
 double y = 0;
public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (UIElement c in LayoutRoot.Children)
            {
                if (c is Button)
                {
                    ((Button)c).Click += Button_Click;
                }
            }
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int k = (int)((Button)e.OriginalSource).Content;
           TextBox1.Text += k;
            int z = (int)((Button)e.OriginalSource).Content;
            TextBox2.Text += z;
            if (k < 1)
            {
                x = (int)(k * Math.Pow(z, 3));
                y = Math.Pow(Math.Log(1 + Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Cos(x + 1)), Math.Exp(k * x));
                double y = Convert.ToString(y);
                TextBox3.Text = y;

            }
            else
                x = (int)(z * (z + 1));
                y = Math.Pow(Math.Log(1 + Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Cos(x + 1)), Math.Exp(k * x));
            double y = Convert.ToString(y);
            TextBox3.Text = y;
        }
```

ввожу 2 значения k z в разные textbox, вывожу результат в третьем. ошибка в конвертировании Y double в string