# Как получить значение из TextBox для переменных

Tags: c#, wpf

Как получить значение из TextBox для переменных k,z? Чего тут не  хватает?

```
int k = 0;
        int z = 0;
        int x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           TextBox1.Text += k;
           TextBox2.Text += z;
            if (k < 1)
            {
                x = (int)(k * Math.Pow(z, 3));
                y = Math.Pow(Math.Log(1 + Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Cos(x + 1)), Math.Exp(k * x));
                TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(y);
            }
            else
                x = (int)(z * (z + 1));
                y = Math.Pow(Math.Log(1 + Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Cos(x + 1)), Math.Exp(k * x));
           TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(y);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Не хватает отмеченной "галочки" слева от ответа - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1281339

Comment: `int k = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text)`, и далее в том же духе и уберите объявление переменных в глобальной области, это лишнее, объявляйте локально в методе.

Comment: Жаль, что вы не захотели понимать тот пример, что вам скинули, не захотели вникать в суть WPF.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ посмотрите в код и в суть вопроса. Здесь не то что очень далеко до WPF, здесь еще и до минимального шарпа не близко.

Comment: @aepot Я смотрю [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1277692/220553) и вижу, что человеку дали решение его задачи, а он это пропустил мимо ушей, что печально. Даже если человек не знает, как и что, ведь можно спросить, верно?

Comment: а что я должен был принять из того примера ?  вы мне рассказываете об отсутствии паттерна mvvm, это просто смешно).. вы серьезно думаете что начинающий поймет то что вы написали? спрос с меня как будто я работаю на вас и речь идет о возможных убытках из-за идиота сотрудника(меня)

Comment: @nosferatuzodd Вам не про MVVM говорят, а про то, что WPF, это в первую очередь привязки и XAML! То есть вы должны уметь пользоваться `<TextBox Text = "{Binding SomeProperty}"/>`, должны понимать как строить интерфейс в XAML. Конкретно в вашем коде (что сейчас в вопросе), вот просто напишите после `InitializeComponent();` еще `DataCotext = this;`, это `double y = 0;` переделайте в свойство `public double Y {get; set;}` и в xaml напишите `<TextBox Text = "{Bindin Y}"/>`, все, сложно? Если вам не нужны привязки и стили, то забудьте про WPF, идите пишите WinForms проект, в нем это норма.

Comment: @nosferatuzodd Поймите, это основы основ того фреймворка, который вы используете, это я не знаю, возьмите Web, там основы это HTML и CSS, возьмите бухгалтерию, там основа наверно Excel и Word. То есть у каждого инструмента есть свои механизмы взаимодействия, а в WPF это как раз привязки и XAML разметка, ну строился он на этом изначально, чтож поделать. Моя цель направить вас в нужное направление, чтоб учили сразу правильные вещи, а смотря как вы постоянно делаете `Convert.ToString(y);`, лично мне грустно становится, ведь таких строк у вас вовсе не должно быть, используя вы привязки.